# How to use G-Suite's shared mailbox (Groups) as sent-from addresses in native mail clients Outlook and Apple Mail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, apple-mail

I set up GSuite and created a Google Group called "info" which is linked to the `info@domain.com` e-mail address.

## What we want to achieve

We are a team of three (each with their seperate private mail address), and all of us should have send / read access to the shared "info" address via *native clients*. This means, that we want to be able to ***send emails from "info@domain.com"** in clients such as Outlook or Apple Mail*.

So far, the only way to send emails from the shared account is by using the G-Mail web application. However, our native clients don't recognize the shared account.

## What I've tried out so far

I have added all wanted users as members of the Google Group and set the required permissions to read / send emails form this group account. I have also come across solutions such as "Google Sync for Microsoft Outlook", but this only works on Windows (no Macs) and for Office (and no other client).

Ideally, I would love to just set up the shared account as a completely seperate mail address and not tied to my personal "user123...@domain.com" address. If that's not possible, how can I send emails from the shared account via non-Gmail-clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.lifewire.com/change-email-sender-name-outlook-1173446 provides an Outlook solution:

In Outlook, click on **File | Account Settings | Account Settings**.

Pick the email account you want to change from, in the list that appears. Click Change.

Look for *Your Name* in the settings pane and enter the "info@domain.com"  you'd like to appear in the From: line of your emails. Click Next then OK.

Also, change your Reply-To field with:

Click on **File | Info |  Account Settings | Account Settings**

Pick the account to revise and click on **Change** then in the Reply-to address text box, change that to "info@domain.com" then **Next** and **Close**.

Comment: In general, I've found out that it's possible to just add the same account twice, one with the private and one with the shared mail address. That way, you can select which address you want to send from when composing a mail